# Unity - C# - CanSeeObject script to look for MULTIPLE gameobjects with same tag; return one

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with integrating different assets.

**What I have**

A 3D house with an autonomous robot moving through rooms on its own. I have a script that can SEE an object, in my case a weapon. If it sees the weapon, it will move towards it.

**The problem**

The problem is that right now, I can only select ONE gameobject it can search for with `public Transform`.

**What I want**

I want the script to search for MULTIPLE gameobjects that have the same tag. When it can see an object with the corresponding tag (defined in a `public string targetTag;`, I want it to move towards this object.

**My script**

To keep it simply, I have stripped (in my idea) unnecessary parts.

**The CanSeeObject.cs script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks.Movement
{
 public class CanSeeObject : Conditional
    {
        [Tooltip("The object that we are searching for. If this value is null then the objectLayerMask will be used")]
        public SharedTransform targetObject;
        [Tooltip("The LayerMask of the objects that we are searching for")]
        public LayerMask objectLayerMask;
        [Tooltip("The field of view angle of the agent (in degrees)")]
        public SharedFloat fieldOfViewAngle = 90;
        [Tooltip("The distance that the agent can see ")]
        public SharedFloat viewDistance = 1000;
        [Tooltip("The offset relative to the pivot position")]
        public SharedVector3 offset;
        [SharedRequired]
        [Tooltip("The object that is within sight")]
        public SharedTransform objectInSight;

        public string targetTag;

        // Returns success if an object was found otherwise failure
        public override TaskStatus OnUpdate()
        {

                if (targetTag == null) {
                    objectInSight.Value = MovementUtility.WithinSight(transform, offset.Value, fieldOfViewAngle.Value, viewDistance.Value, objectLayerMask);
                } else { // If the target is not null then determine if that object is within sight
                    objectInSight.Value = MovementUtility.WithinSight(transform, offset.Value, fieldOfViewAngle.Value, viewDistance.Value, GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My `targetTag` is `GUN` in the inspector.

As you can see, I am trying to achieve this by using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag)`. It's not working due to it being an array with multiple `GUNS` hidden in the house.

**Error 1**

```
Assets/Behavior Designer Movement/Scripts/Tasks/CanSeeObject.cs(46,79): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks.Movement.MovementUtility.WithinSight(UnityEngine.Transform, UnityEngine.Vector3, float, float, UnityEngine.Transform)' has some invalid arguments
```

**Error 2**

```
Assets/Behavior Designer Movement/Scripts/Tasks/CanSeeObject.cs(46,79): error CS1503: Argument `#5' cannot convert `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' expression to type `UnityEngine.Transform'
```

I have no idea how to fix this.. Thanks in advance for your help!!

**UPDATE - WithinSight function**

```
public static Transform WithinSight(Transform transform, Vector3 positionOffset, float fieldOfViewAngle, float viewDistance, LayerMask objectLayerMask)
        {
            Transform objectFound = null;
            var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, viewDistance, objectLayerMask);
            if (hitColliders != null) {
                float minAngle = Mathf.Infinity;
                for (int i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; ++i) {
                    float angle;
                    Transform obj;
                    // Call the WithinSight function to determine if this specific object is within sight
                    if ((obj = WithinSight(transform, positionOffset, fieldOfViewAngle, viewDistance, hitColliders[i].transform, false, out angle, objectLayerMask.value)) != null) {
                        // This object is within sight. Set it to the objectFound GameObject if the angle is less than any of the other objects
                        if (angle < minAngle) {
                            minAngle = angle;
                            objectFound = obj;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return objectFound;
        }
```

**EDIT: More WithinSight functions(?)**

```
public static Transform WithinSight(Transform transform, Vector3 positionOffset, float fieldOfViewAngle, float viewDistance, Transform targetObject)
        {
            float angle;
            return WithinSight(transform, positionOffset, fieldOfViewAngle, viewDistance, targetObject, false, out angle, ignoreRaycast);
        }




 private static Transform WithinSight(Transform transform, Vector3 positionOffset, float fieldOfViewAngle, float viewDistance, Transform targetObject, bool usePhysics2D, out float angle, int layerMask)
        {
            // The target object needs to be within the field of view of the current object
            var direction = targetObject.position - (transform.TransformPoint(positionOffset));
            direction.y = 0;
            if (usePhysics2D) {
                angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, transform.up);
            } else {
                angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, transform.forward);
            }
            if (direction.magnitude < viewDistance && angle < fieldOfViewAngle * 0.5f) {
                // The hit agent needs to be within view of the current agent
                if (LineOfSight(transform, positionOffset, targetObject, usePhysics2D, layerMask) != null) {
                    return targetObject; // return the target object meaning it is within sight
                } else if (targetObject.GetComponent<Collider>() == null) {
                    // If the linecast doesn't hit anything then that the target object doesn't have a collider and there is nothing in the way
                    if (targetObject.gameObject.activeSelf)
                        return targetObject;
                }
            }
            // return null if the target object is not within sight
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Dude post your `WithinSight` funcction. We don't know what the parameter looks like without it.

Comment: You are passing `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag)` into the method, that presumably is the issue based on the error you are getting. The method you call does not want an array of gameObjects, but a transform. You could try `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag)[0].transform`

Comment: @Programmer sorry I'm new to the whole programming business, I overlooked it. See my edit! Thanks :)

Comment: There is only one `WithinSight` function and the code you posted above is what it looks like?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre this worked! But, after finding all items (3 in total), it gives me the following error:

`IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.` It is referring to `targetObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (targetTag) [0].transform;` (I made this single line of code right after the OnUpdate() call)

Comment: @Programmer there are some more I see now. Maybe this helps? See edited post. Regarding the problem: it works, but now I'm getting the array error (see my last comment). Any ideas on how to solve the error from popping up?

Comment: Just do an empty check on the array you get back before trying to access any of its elements.